# Structure JNA returns wrong value

Tags: java, c++, scala, java-native-interface, jna

From C++ code I am getting the structure.But all the values I am getting is default  value.Below is my c++ code

```
extern "C" 
{ 
PDFCONTENTDATA GetPDFContentData(LPTSTR lptszS3FileURL)
{
PDFCONTENTDATA pdfContentData;
pdfContentData.m_uiRasterDPI = 100;

return pdfContentData;
}
};
```

Below is my java/scala code

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({ "m_uiRasterDPI"})
public class tagPDFContentData extends Structure {

    public static class ByValue extends tagPDFContentData implements Structure.ByValue { }
    public static class ByReference extends tagPDFContentData implements Structure.ByReference { }
    public volatile int m_uiRasterDPI;
}


trait CDocuLinkCoreServices extends Library{
  def GetPDFContentData(value: Pointer):  tagPDFContentData.ByValue
}
```

But I am getting

> m_uiRasterDPI= 0

where it should return 100.

Comment: Please let me know why this is marked as negative.

Comment: Hm. Why is it downvoted?

Comment: @Oo.oO  Can you please help me mate on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo057

To make a smooth call to `JNA`, there is a Java class `recipeNo057.Data`. This class is super simple

```
package recipeNo057;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.WString;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;

@Structure.FieldOrder({ "field" })
public class Data extends Structure {

    public static class ByValue extends Data implements Structure.ByValue { }
    public static class ByReference extends Data implements Structure.ByReference { }
    public volatile int field;

}
```

on the other side (`C++` side) we have "the same" structure.

```
typedef struct data {
  int field;
}
```

Scala binds all that stuff together by "linking" `Java` based class, `JNA` based call to native code, and native code in `C++` itself.

```
trait HelloWorld extends Library {

  def GetData(m: WString) : Data.ByValue;

}

object HelloJNA {

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {

    val libc   = Native.load( "HelloWorld", classOf[HelloWorld] )

    var result = libc.GetData( new WString("I am passing String!") )
    println("Result: " + result.field);

  }
}
```

**Note**

It's important to pay attention to type match between `Java` structures and `C++` structures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But in my case I am still getting the wrong value.

Comment: However your structure is running fine when I do the same.

Comment: The only case, I can see, might be related to different type. E.g. inside C++ code you have something different than "int". In my case, if you change `int field` to `double field` you will get `0` as well. So, make sure your types match.

Comment: Ah! I got the problem there was some extern c issue.That's why it was showing the default value.

Comment: .oOo. Cool! Have fun with JNA! ;) .oOo.

Comment: When I am adding more than 2 or 3 value some are returning default or garbage value.I think might be memory allocation issue.Any idea? @Oo.oO

Comment: It looks like it was all about struct padding :( But still, I have no idea how to deal with `boolean` ;)

Comment: `boolean` in JNA uses the C interpretation: It's a plain 32-bit `int`, 0 = `false`, nonzero = `true`.

Comment: @DanielWiddis the fun starts when you have legacy code with `bool`, `_Bool`, `jniboolean`, etc. and you don't pay attention to whether your structures are packed or not.